# Flutter - How to complete/await function execution before build method?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am simply trying to set an ID in this function:

```
      _getLastWorkoutId() async {
    
    try {
      var snapshot = await usersRef
          .doc(currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('workouts')
          .orderBy('workoutDate', descending: true)
          .limit(1)
          .snapshots()
          .first; 
    //The execution moves to build method from here------and then returns
      for (var element in snapshot.docs) {
        workoutId = element.id;
        setState(() {
          _isWorkoutIdSet = true;
        });
      }
      //return snapshot;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    //return null;
  }
```

I call it in the initState:

```
    @override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  super.initState();
  //var snapshot = _getLastWorkoutId();
  _getLastWorkoutId();
}
```

The problem is, the for loop executes after the build function is called. I don't want that to happen.

Comment: I tried but it needs to return something, I am not sure how it would work as I am not returning anything.

Comment: I thought this shouldn't be so tough as even a synchronous call to the function should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
Future<bool> _value;

@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  super.initState();
  _value = _getLastWorkoutId();
}
```

And in your `build` method you have:

```
 FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: _value,
    builder: (
      BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot,
    ) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.data){
           //update view 
         }else{
           //update view
         }
      }
    }
```

The method can be like this:

```
   _getLastWorkoutId() async {
        try {
          var snapshot = await usersRef
              .doc(currentUser!.uid)
              .collection('workouts')
              .orderBy('workoutDate', descending: true)
              .limit(1)
              .snapshots()
              .first; 
          for (var element in snapshot.docs) {
            workoutId = element.id;
            return true;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        }
      }
```

[Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) you can find more about `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Why bool? Also, what do I return where you have written update view? I just need to update a value.

Comment: Change the data type to whatever your method returns. Also, in the build method you should update the UI!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should solve the issue:

First, on build method:

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _getLastWorkoutId(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    return Container(); // here goes whatever it is you had before.
  }
);
```

then on `_getLastWorkoutId()`:

```
Future<void> _getLastWorkoutId() async {
  ...
}
```

That way the function returns a future of void instead of void, allowing `FutureBuilder` to do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable to save state. For example

```
var isLoading = true;
```

At the end of try block in func _getLastWorkoutId reset isLoading to false.
Then call setState or update state by better way used state management likes provider, bloc, get.
In build widget add check isLoading like this

```
return isLoading ? YourLoadingIndicatorWidget() : DisplayDataWidget();
```